# Will hosting documents on AWS reduce our load?

Tags: server, aws

Due to partnerships, we are required to host our website through our partner company. However, we had an idea that perhaps we could offload the document storage to an AWS document server.  The thinking is that we could serve the html from our server, and serve any large document files from the AWS server, which would greatly reduce our bandwidth load.

Having never used AWS, can I simply provide a relatively secure AWS URL to the browser which will pull the document from AWS and bypass our web server altogether?

Comment: `relatively secure AWS URL` Which are the security constraints? Is it some kind of Intranet (access authenticated through username/passwords or other kinds of credentials). Also, how would that reduce bandwith load?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure of the security details yet... But it would reduce load because my web server would no longer serve the large documents, the AWS server would.  The users browser would get the HTML from my server, and when they clicked on the URL for "Big Document 1", it would open it directly from AWS.

Comment: Dumb question but what does reducing your bandwidth load get you? You will pay a lot more for those same bytes off of s3 than you will off of many typical connection setups.

Comment: If security was an issue, if you host on an Amazon VPS instead of S3, you can implement the necessary security on that remote server (perhaps having it do a callback to your main server to validate credentials)

Comment: @Wyatt Barnett - Really?  I thought AWS was a fairly inexpensive solution?  Something to think about though.  I'll review the cost to bump our bandwidth vs hosting on AWS.  Thanks for the insight!

Comment: @Scottie -- yes and no, it adds up real fast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can indeed. In fact, you can simply have your Web server send links that look like yourbucket.s3.amazonaws.com/yourdir/yourfile.txt

You can even use cloudfront as a cdn, and optionally protect your files from direct access.

You'll have to do some reading on s3 as a minimum, and cloudfront as well if you want.

Also depending on your framework you will want to search for a module to stick things directly on the remote server. For instance boto for Python/Django